# posting the data using httpput in android

Tags: android, http, put

I have a problem in posting the data to server by using httpput methods in android.I have to send feedback to server and getting json response. but i am getting **404 bad request**. but i dont know where is the problem.

I am strucked here and didn't find any solution. Any suggestions?

My code is as follows:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPut put = new HttpPut(getString(R.string.feedBack));

List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userId", "8"));
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("feedback",feedbackMessage
        .getText().toString()));
put.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
put.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
put.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));

HttpResponse response = client.execute(put);

Log.d(tag, "Result" + response.getStatusLine());
```

Comment: are you getting 404 (aka not found) or (00 bad request??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not initializing a URL object and passing in simple `String`.

You should do this instead:

```
URL url = new URL(getString(R.string.feedBack));
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPut put= new HttpPut(url);
```

And it should work.

Comment: What is the difference between those two?I already used the url there but not intialized. I used "myurl" in place of url but i didn't initialized like what you said just used myurl. but no use.Like HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPut put= new HttpPut("myurl");

Comment: You need to initialize that URL object, in the snippet above, you are only passing a `String` to your `HttpPut` object.

Comment: I assigned the string with my url.

Comment: Exactly, you gave string that could be in a wrong format or the object `HttpPut` could have done something you didn't want, because you didn't wrap that url represented as a `String` in `URL` object.